# Am not getting anything when starting my camera in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Have got a strange problem with my app.  Have created a button in my main menu, and when clicked it should take me to my camera with the intent i set.  however i am just getting a blank white screen.

here are my Camera.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class Camera extends Activity{



public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
 }
```

In my manifest file:

```
  </activity)
<activity android:name=".Camera"></activity>
 </application>
```

and the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please see my answer and if it is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me well for opening camera without declaring any permissions in the Manifest file.

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Camera extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn_cal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cal);
        btn_cal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Hope this helps you somehow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need permissions if you're taking pictures via intent.

Here's what I have to take it in an app I wrote:

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "photo.jpg");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"my decription");

```
    cameraResultURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    //create new Intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraResultURI);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_ACTIVITY);
```

Comment: Thank you, but am still getting a blank white screen. do i need to create a xml file aswell?